# VS 2019 extension to run resource generator on project load

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

We want to exclude the designer.cs files, generated from RESX files, from our repositories.

To achieve this, we need to make VS run the resource generator at project load (because the resource generation tool only runs when a RESX file is changed).

This triggers two questions:

1. Is there already an extension which does this (can't find one).
2. If not, which SDK class/event can I hook into so I can run the resource generator when a Project loads? (I appreciate I'm then going to have to iterate through the files in the project).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there already an extension which does this (can't find one)

We can search extensions in [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=vs2019&sortBy=Downloads). Most of them for currently are for free. But it seems there's no such extension there to do behavior as you expected.

> If not, which SDK class/event can I hook into so I can run the
>   resource generator when a Project loads? (I appreciate I'm then going
>   to have to iterate through the files in the project).

Maybe the event that you're looking for is [IvsSolutionEvents3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents3?view=visualstudiosdk-2017). The [IVsSolutionEvents3.OnAfterLoadProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents3.onafterloadproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) or [IVsSolutionEvents3.OnAfterOpenProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents3.onafteropenproject?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) method can help.

In addition: Topic about how to detect and manage solution and project loading see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/managing-project-loading-in-a-solution?view=vs-2019#handle-solution-load-events).